# Change value of slider using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a UI slider that starts at 0 million and goes up to 20000 million.

I want to change the value when it reaches 1000 to say 1 milliard, and when it reaches 20000 to say 20 milliard.

For example, the value 1100 million should output '1 milliard 100'.
 i have another question ,i want to that this platform shows 1milliard 100 but i can return 1100 million.it is for example.how can i do it?
I don't know how can I do it?

```html
  <span><a id="minamountr">0</a>million</span>
  <span><a id="maxamountr">20000</a>million</span>
</div>
<script>
  $(".sliderr").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 20000,
    values: [0, 20000],
    range: true,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#minamountr").html(ui.values[0]);
      $("#maxamountr").html(ui.values[1]);
    }
  });
</script>





        i try it but it doesnn't work:
change: function (event, ui) {
                    value = ui.value;
                    mily = Math.floor(value / 1000);
                    milyoun = value % 1000 
                    if (mily > 1) {
                       milyString = 'milliyard';
                    } else {
                       milyString = 'million';
                    }            
                    if (mily == 0) {
                        altValue = milyoun + ' ' + 'million';
                    } 

                    alert(altValue);

                    $(event.target).slider("option", "altValue", 
                         altValue);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understand that when your slider value is 1000 then it should shows 1 and when 2000 it should shows 2 in the minamountr. And similar case for maxamountr. So, very simple see below the example:

```
<span><a id="minamountr">0</a>میلیون</span>
<span><a id="maxamountr">20000</a>میلیون</span>

<script>
  $(".sliderr").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 20000,
    values: [0, 20000],
    range: true,
    step: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
    ( ui.values[0] % 1000 == 0 ) ? $("#minamountr").html(ui.values[0] / 1000.0) :  $("#minamountr").html(ui.values[0]);

    ( ui.values[1] % 1000 == 0 ) ? $("#maxamountr").html(ui.values[1] / 1000.0) :  $("#minamountr").html(ui.values[1]);


    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work.and i want to write milliard too.

Comment: could you please the plugin name you are using for this. Or the cdn link of  plugin.

Comment: it's jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cunstmyr/ If I look at this, this is working fine. When value reached to 1000 it shows 1, and when reached to 2000 it shows 2...

Comment: so what do you want. Your requirements showed that you want this, but you are saying that you dont want this.

Comment: I want to show like it,the word of million and millard change,too.thanks for helping me.for 1 to 1 milliard should show .million 100,million 200,.. .million 900,milliard 1,100 milliard 1,200 milliard 1,...,milliard 2,100 milliard 2..., milliard 20

Comment: I try like that i write but that isn't true.in my language dir is rtl

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alihassan87613/1jkLn9tf/14/ Now please have look at this. Thank you.

Comment: sorry,i have a question,i used it in advance search and i want show number like 1milliard 200 but return to sql server 1200,this code doesn't return like it.

Comment: I think the question you asked me, I answered you. Its a platform to resolve issues. Not to do work of you. Please understand the platform is just for resolving issues. And the modification you want from me, this should be another question. That is not fair. Thank you.

Comment: ok,you mean it doesn't work that i want. i have another question ,i want to that  this platform shows 1milliard 100 but i can return 1100 million.it is for example.thank you.